# How should we configure response object with out using @XMLRootElement

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf, aegis

I am Generating Rest services using CXF Aegis data binding here, I don't want to use @XMLRootElement annotations. for that, I am using @Path, @PathParam annotations but here for the Response object What should use I don't have clarity please help to resolve this.

Here is the code for rest service configuration. Here don't know how to configure that List

```
   @POST
   @Path("/getworkorders/")
   @Consumes("application/json")
   @Produces("application/json")
   public List<WorkOrderNeutral>getWorkOrders(@PathParam("BaseFilterNeutral")BaseFilterNeutral baseFilterNeutral) throws ServiceException;
```

here is my data binding provider

```
<bean id="jaxbProviderAegis-workOrder" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.aegis.AegisElementProvider"/>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `@XmlRootElement` if you are using Jackson as your JSON provider.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am getting Object like     
 **[{"userName":"sathish","userId":7},{"userName":"mani","userId":101}]**      But i need  **{ objectName : [{"userName":"sathish","userId":7},{"userName":"mani","userId":101}]**